# Exist a generic library of validators for obj-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, validation

I wonder if already exist a generic library of validator suitable for a iPhone project (or better, bussines objects) for obj-c.

Things like:

```
Validator.IsNotEmpty..
Validator.IsValidEmail..
Validator.IsValidZipCode..
Validator.IsValidRegex..
Validator.IsInRange..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a standard *validation pattern* in Cocoa, including Cocoa Touch, called [Key-Value Validation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/Validation.html) that you should conform to if you want to validate user input other than through an NSFormatter.

In essence, for a property `name` that you want validated, you implement a method following this pattern:

```
- (BOOL)validateName:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)error;
```

Then, when you want to validate a property before setting it from your UI, you just use:

```
NSString *proposedName = [[nameField.stringValue copy] autorelease];
NSError *nameError;

if ([person validateValue:&proposedName forKey:@"name" error:&nameError]) {
    person.name = proposedName;
} else {
    // present nameError to the user in a reasonable way
}
```

Note that you **do not** invoke `-validateValue:forKey:error:` or `-validateName:error:` method in your `-setName:` method.  Instead, you invoke your `-setName:` method (as I do via dot syntax above) once you know the value you're passing for it will be valid.

Also, read the document on Key-Value Validation that I mentioned above to understand why `proposedName` is an autoreleased copy of a field's string value, instead of just its string value.

If you're implementing something more complicated than per-property validation, such as whole-object validation or even object graph validation, be sure to see how the Core Data framework on Mac OS X handles it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of anything. If it's something you want I would use one of the regex libraries available for Cocoa Touch, you should be able to find regex examples of those tests pretty easily.